# Trying to filter data based on start and end date

Tags: python, django, django-filters

I am using django filter package to filter data based on start, 
end date and class of dues fields defined in my models. The problem is If I select only class_of_fields data is filtered but when I 
select start and end_date along with class_of_dues no data is filtered below are my codes

**models.py**

```
class DuesLevy(models.Model):
    class_of_dues = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=options.CHOOSE, choices=options.CLASS_OF_DUES, blank=True)
    payment_circle = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=options.CHOOSE, choices=options.PAYMENT_CIRCLE)
    payment_option = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=options.CHOOSE, choices=options.PAYMENT_OPTION)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=30,  null=True, blank=True, editable=False, default=my_rand)
    payment_channel = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=options.CHOOSE, choices=options.PAYMENT_CHANNEL_TYPE)
    payment_date = models.DateField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    date_recorded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.amount
```

**filter.py**

```
from .models import DuesLevy, User
from django_filters import widgets
import django_filters 
from django import forms
from django_select2 import forms as s2forms
from backend import options


class DuesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class_of_dues = django_filters.CharFilter(
                    widget=s2forms.Select2Widget(choices=options.CLASS_OF_DUES, 
                    attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    start_date = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='payment_date', 
       widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'type':'date'}), lookup_expr='lt',label='Start Date')
    end_date = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='payment_date', 
      widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'type':'date'}), lookup_expr='gt',label='End Date')

    user = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=User.objects.all(), 
              widget=s2forms.ModelSelect2Widget(
                  attrs={'class': 'form-control'},
                  model=User,
                  search_fields=['member_id__icontains'],
                  ))
    class Meta():
        model = DuesLevy
        fields = ('class_of_dues',  'start_date', 'end_date')
```

**views.py**

```
class ListMemberDues(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/backoffice/'

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = DuesLevy.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        query_filter = DuesFilter(request.GET, queryset)

        context = {
            'form':query_filter.form,
            'query':query_filter,
        }
        return render(request, 'dashboard/list-member-dues.html', context)
```

**templates.html**

```
  <form class="form-inline d-flex justify-content-around">
      <div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">Class Of Dues</div>
            </div>
           {{ form.class_of_dues }}
          </div>
      </div>


       <div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
           <div class="input-group">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">Start Date</div>
             </div>
            {{ form.start_date }}
           </div>
       </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
           <div class="input-group">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">End Date</div>
             </div>
              {{ form.end_date }}
           </div>
       </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Filter</button>
      {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
    {% if request.user %}
    <div class="row p-3 bg-light">               
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Account Details</h3>
        <h4>{{ request.user.first_name }} {{ single.user.last_name }}</h4>
        <h4>Phone {{ single.user.phone1 }}</h4>
        <h4>LCDA: {{ request.user.lcda }}</h4>
        <h4>Zone: {{ request.user.zone }}</h4>
        <h4>Area: {{ request.user.area }}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img style="width: 200px; height: auto;" src="{{ request.user.additionalprofile.get_image_url }}" alt="">
      </div>

    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Payment Date</th>
            <th>Categories</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Channel</th>
            <th>Transaction ID</th>
        </tr>
        {% if query %}
          {% for q in query.qs %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{ q.date_recorded }}</td>
              <td>{{ q.class_of_dues }}</td>
              <td>&#8358;{{ q.amount }}</td>
              <td>{{ q.payment_channel }}</td>
              <td>{{ q.transaction_id }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}

        {% endif %}
    </table>
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have `lt` and `gt` the wrong way round? As you have it, you would match when the start date is less than the user provided data and the end data was greater than the provided date

Comment: I have altered it but yet it did not work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the corresponding lines in the DuesFilter class are pointing to the wrong fields. The two lines in question should be:

```
start_date = django_filters.DateFilter(
    field_name='start_date',  # not payment_date
    widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'type':'date'}), 
    lookup_expr='gt',  # Include dates after the start date (exclusive)
    label='Start Date')

end_date = django_filters.DateFilter(
    field_name='end_date',  # not payment_date
    widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'type':'date'}), 
    lookup_expr='lt',  # Include dates before the end date (exclusive)
    label='End Date')
```

I'm going out on a limb to guess you really wanted to *include* dates between start_date and end_date and have updated the `lookup_expr` to reflect that.

Comment: thank you so much and God bless you, I have been battling this for weeks, thanks once again I appreciate